# How can I order by date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a query (mysql).
I have to `order by date ASC` tha problem is that I also have empty date in the table. Mysql set them to 0000-00-00, so when I order by date those dates are shown first, but i need to put the "empty dates" at the end, how can I do?

Example:

```
0000-00-00
2011-01-01
2010-12-12
```

Query: .... `ORDER BY date ASC`

Results should be:

```
2010-12-12
2011-01-01
0000-00-00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF(date = '0000-00-00', 1, 0) ASC, date ASC
```

Comment: @Marco Yep, real dates first, so shouldn't real dates be 0 when order by asc? :) think again?

Comment: @SalmanA: yes, correct, my fault. +1 for xdazz!! Maybe sleeping a little more helps me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY date ASC
```

you could do

```
SELECT *, IF(date > 0, 1, 0) AS has_date
FROM table
ORDER BY has_date ASC, date ASC
```

I believe that would do it for you.